# auto sort method to append function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've dynamical list that user can add li (items) to a ul. They can choose level 1,2 and 3.. for now they all append to ul, with no sorting function. I want the level 1 always on the 1st when been inserted, level 2 will come along and then followed by level 3, think of it like priority. for example I've 4 item in a list with level 2, then when a new item with level 1 come in, it doesn't append on the last item, but the 1st.

I'm wondering must I write the sort function on my own, thx

Comment: There is obviously [array.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort), but you should indeed write some code to use it.

Comment: thx! it's easy for a static list, any example for dynamic list? I would use my own method than array.sort

Comment: There's no difference for static and dynamic lists. It's just an array.

Comment: Instead of using `.append()`, search the list for the place you want to insert, and use `.before()` or `.after()`.

Answer (score 0):

A method to do this will be attach attribute to li elements at specific level like:

```
<ul>
    <li class="level1">this is level 1</li>
    <li class="level1">this is level 1</li>
    <li class="level1">this is level 1</li>
    <li class="level2">this is level 2</li>
    <li class="level2">this is level 2</li>
    <li class="level3">this is level 3</li>
    <li class="level3">this is level 3</li>
</ul>
```

Then do insert at appropriate level.

Check a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Hms7Y/

Comment: awesome! what if I don't have any markup for lvl1,2,3? I jst hv an empty ul?

Comment: Also, there was a typing error in setting the class name in new li. Fixed. http://jsfiddle.net/Hms7Y/15/