# sorting and appending li to ul asc

Tags: javascript, jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/Hms7Y/14/

the code above work well for inserting item according to 'level' without using any complex sorting algo, but there's a problem, when there is no ready markup, the level 2 will be still on top of level 1..

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('button').click(function() {
    var lvl = $('select').val();
    var ref = $('li.level' + lvl).last();
    var newLi =  $('<li class="level'+ lvl + '">' + lvl + ' </li>');

    console.log(ref);

    (ref.length > 0) ? newLi.insertAfter(ref) : $("ul").append(newLi);
  });
});
```

Comment: Can you explain your problem some more, it's not clear what you are asking.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan When you click Add, it adds the number from the menu to the list. The list is supposed to be sorted, with all 1's, then all 2's, then all 3's. Buf if the first thing you add is 2 or 3, it doesn't work.

Comment: Did you see the suggestion in one of your questions to preload your list with hidden elements with each level? That way, `ref` will always find something, and you don't need to do anything special.

Comment: @Barmar no.. where is it?

Comment: In the second comment to the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/19442457/1491895

Comment: omg I didn't see that! TQ!

Comment: @Barmar because of my li has strip effect using even class, so with 3 hidden li the effect broke, how can I fix that?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know about that. I guess you'll have to use the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I have edited you fiddle to work as you expect: http://jsfiddle.net/Hms7Y/23/

Basically I have added this control on every click:

```
if($("ul").children().length>0){
    $("li").each(function(){
        if(lvl <= parseInt($(this).html())){
            newLi.insertBefore($(this));
        }else{
            newLi.insertAfter($(this));
        }
    });
}else{
    $("ul").append(newLi);
}
```